# How to test Angular Web App with RobotFramework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safari, appium, robotframework

I have a small Angular web app to test with RobotFramework.  The app is designed to be used on an iPad.

In this scenario, is it typical to use the RobotFramework Appium Library or the ExtendedSelenium2Library which is designed for Angular with a Safari browser?  In the case of the latter, is it possible to set the Safari User Agent to iPad in RobotFramework.  How?